# How to make multiple UPSERT in Yii2?

Tags: mysql, yii2

I am using Yii2 advance template. I have to insert 1000 to 2000 records in MySql Database.

Is it possible to make Multiple **UPSERT Query** in **Yii2**.

Please help me with your suggestion/answers. Thank you.

Answer (score 5):

Since version 2.0.14 you have upsert() available.

Your code could look something like this:

```
$insertValues = [
    'timestamp' => gmdate('YmdH'),
    'entry_id' => $this->id,
    'view_count' => 1,
];
$updateValues = ['view_count' => new \yii\db\Expression('table_name.view_count + 1')];
Yii::$app->db->createCommand()->upsert('table_name', $insertValues, $updateValues)->execute();
```

You can find the full documentation here: https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-db-command#upsert()-detail

Answer (score 4):

Try with modified [batchInsert()](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-db-command.html#batchInsert()-detail) method:

```
$db = \Yii::$app->db;
$sql = $db->queryBuilder->batchInsert($table, $fields, $rows);
$db->createCommand($sql . ' ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE')->execute();
```

Comment: Thanks Bizley but is there maximum limit of batchInesrt ?

Comment: It depends on the overall system performance, timeout and memory limits.

Comment: it is throwing yii\db\Exception

Comment: It doesn't seems to be correct. You mixed https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-db-command#batchInsert()-detail with https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-db-querybuilder#batchInsert()-detail. Also ignoring `$params` generated by [`batchInsert()`](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-db-querybuilder#batchInsert()-detail)  also seems to be incorrect (`getSql()` may return SQL string with params placeholders instead of actual values).

Comment: Oh, right, it was unnecessary edit. I've never tested the original idea here though.