# How to streamline concurrent saves in Yii2?

Tags: php, mysql, activerecord, yii2

My application is exposing an API to sync-up data from an external system. The corresponding controller uses QueryParamAuth for authentication, and after some preliminary checks, populates an ActiveRecord model product with the posted data, and attempts to save it using `$product->save()`

The id field for this model was auto-generated via migrate/create as:

```
'id' => $this->primaryKey(),
```

Now, in the initial sync, all the products data needs to be synced up from the external system on to the new application. Thus, external system is making multiple asynchronous calls to a URL exposed by the above controller. However, I'm repeatedly getting one of the following two SQL Errors during `$product->save()`, resulting in only ~250 records getting saved out of a test batch of ~375.

The first, and most common error that I'm getting is:

```
SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '7' for key 'PRIMARY'
The SQL being executed was: INSERT INTO `product` (`sku`, `name`, `quantity`, `created_at`, `updated_at`, `created_by`, `updated_by`, `id`) VALUES (NULL, 'Copies', 0, NOW(), NOW(), 3, 3, 7)
```

Another error, that I'm getting towards the end of the batch is:

```
SQLSTATE[22003]: Numeric value out of range: 1264 Out of range value for column 'id' at row 1
The SQL being executed was: INSERT INTO `product` (`sku`, `name`, `quantity`, `created_at`, `updated_at`, `created_by`, `updated_by`, `id`) VALUES (NULL, 'Brochures', 0, NOW(), NOW(), 3, 3, 9223372036854775807)
```

Please note that the table was initially empty, and the first record got created with id 1. The erratic jump in AUTO_INCREMENT id seems to happen randomly. The last saved record carries the id 1816263484.

What can I do to avoid these SQL errors?

Comment: I would go with SQL `transaction` and `upsert` or `batch insert`. Also important is what SQL engine is used - InnoDB, myISAM or some non-relational? For example InnoDB locks on row level so transactioned upserts should be safe. See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41178664/how-to-make-multiple-upsert-in-yii2

Comment: InnoDB is being used. However, since ActiveRecord is db independent, I don't know how to use row level locks here for this purpose. `upsert` is not the right behavior here, as I don't wish to update the existing record simply because two processes are concurrently tying to add 1 record each. Unfortunately `batch insert` is not an option because each API call is posting the data for a single record.

Comment: @lubosdz you don't need transaction for simple insert-like queries. InnoDB uses locks for auto_increment columns automatically. Those errors are not caused by race condition in first place.

Comment: I've raised a bug in Yii2 as the id column shouldn't have been included in the generated SQL Command in the first place. The inclusion of id column is the source of all issues here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After raising the issue on Yii2 repository and much diagnostic discussion there, it turns out the following code in the model was responsible for it:

```
public function behaviors()
{
    return [
        ...
        'uuid' => [
            'class' => UUIDBehavior::className(),
            'column' => 'id',
        ],
    ];
}
```

After removing the `uuid` behavior rule, the problem vanished.

[Michal Hynčica](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70973706/how-to-streamline-concurrent-saves-in-yii2/70973771#comment125467269_70973771) was right is assuming that I'm setting the value of id, though I didn't know it was happening here.

Special thanks to [lubosdz](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1485984/lubosdz) for attempting to help here as well as on GitHub.

Answer (score -2):

I've managed to solve it in a hacky manner. Leaving the code here in case it helps someone else.

I've replaced `$product->save();` with `$this->attemptParallelSave($product);` The code for this function is as below:

```
private function attemptParallelSave($record)
{
    try {
        $saved = $record->save();
        if (!$saved && $record->errors) {
            throw new \Exception(\json_encode($record->errors));
        }
    } catch (\yii\db\IntegrityException $e) {
        if ($record->isNewRecord) {
            $record->id = null;
            sleep(\random_int(1, 5)); //Sleep for a random duration to reduce contention
            $this->attemptParallelSave($record);
        } else {
            throw $e;
        }
    }
}
```

Although this is less elegant than obtaining a lock (say, using mutex), but it is working correctly without any visible performance impact.

Comment: The real question is, whether this solution actually solves the original problem, or simply tries to avoid it. Based on those errors it seems, that although the `id` column is declared as `primaryKey()` (which for mysql means `INTEGER AUTO_INCREMENT`) you are attempting to save some specific value into the `id` field. The first error means, that you are trying to save record with same `id` value that already exists. The second error means, that you are trying to save value bigger than what can be stored in INTEGER.

Comment: Your solution basically removes the value in `id` attribute if the first attempt doesn't pass. Because of that during next attempt the `id` is auto generated and has no problem passing. But you are losing original value of ID field. If you don't need to keep original ID, you can simply set `$record->id = null`  before first save attempt and it will work. If you need to keep original ID, you need to change the column type to `BIGINT` and decide how are you going to handle duplicate IDs.

Comment: Also, your solution have 2 potential problems. First, it can create duplicate records because if you receive item with same ID, instead of throwing it away you reset id field and save it again. Second, if the `IntegrityException` is caused by something else than `id` your recursion will become infinite.

Comment: You have assumed that I'm attempting to save specific value in the `id` field. This assumption is wrong altogether. I've instantiated a new active record, and id will be auto assigned on save. You other comments are built on top of the same wrong assumption, and hence invalid.

Comment: Your comment regarding recursion leading to infinite loop is valid though. I'll modify the code to run validations first to check for other issues, before attempting the recursion.

Comment: I didn't assume that, I've covered both cases. As I've said in my second comment if you don't need the original ID, you can simply set `$record->id = null;` before first `save()` call and it will pass even without that recursion.

Comment: It is always null for a fresh active record unless you manually set it. The reason I was getting duplicates is because multiple API calls were parallely trying to insert the records in the table.

Comment: The point is, that you are setting it. DBMS has its own way to deal with parallel inserts and it would never assign duplicate key in auto increment column. And it would never try to assign `9223372036854775807` as auto increment value in INTEGER column. Also the query would have `NULL` in `id` field in queries that caused errors but they clearly don't have `NULL` there.

Comment: I'm not setting it. Given your experience with Yii2, I'm sure you would understand how ActiveRecord instantiation works. I don't understand why you are insisting that I'm setting it?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/241721/discussion-between-michal-hyncica-and-gaurav).